# Stereo vison with Compute module via SSH

Tags: camera, raspicam, streaming-video, compute-module

I started working with a Raspberry Pi Compute Module and 2 PiCamera after long time. I lost all the notes about our old class project, I quite don't remember all our procedures

Each camera is connected and works well (Tried raspistill/raspivid command).

I found this instruction stored into a .sh file that "should" start the stream of the 2 cameras.

```
sudo uv4l --sched-rr --driver raspicam --video_nr=0 --stereoscopic-mode=side_by_side --encoding=mjpeg --width=1280 --height=480 --server-option='--port=9000'
```

I am able to access in ssh mode to my Raspberry and launch this sh file.
I would to receive the video stream in my computer.
I tried to record stream with VLC but adresses like http://:9000 does not work.

Can anyone help me whit these problems

1) the .sh script generates these lines

```
<notice> [core] Trying driver 'raspicam' from built-in drivers...
<warning> [core] Driver 'raspicam' not found
<notice> [core] Trying driver 'raspicam' from external plug-in's...
<notice> [driver] Dual Raspicam Video4Linux2 Driver v1.9.36 built Apr  8 2016
<notice> [driver] Selected format: 1280x480, encoding: mjpeg, JPEG Video Capture
<notice> [driver] Framerate max. 30 fps
<notice> [driver] ROI: 0, 0, 1, 1
<notice> [core] Device detected!
<notice> [core] Registering device node /dev/video0
```

but how to know if the stream is properly generated? How to access to dev/video0?

2) how to get the stream with VLC? All my tries went wrong

3) Is there any other better way to stream the stereo cameras?

Tank you all in advance.

Comment: read this: http://www.linux-projects.org/uv4l/tutorials/streaming-server/

Answer (score 1):

After following [the link provided by strumpet](http://www.linux-projects.org/uv4l/tutorials/streaming-server/), the correct address to stream the video with VLC is

```
http://raspberrypi:port/stream/video.mjpeg
```

where raspberry is the IP and port is the selected port in the uv4l command (9000 in my case).

Comment: BTW Typically, in a use case where you want to use network-type access to something and that is on __the same__ device you use the special host name `localhost` {a.k.a. the IPv4 address: `127.0.0.1` or the Ipv6 one: `::1`}.